# Insert array into SQL query

Tags: sql, arrays

I am running the following SQL query...

```
$user = 'salesrep_83';
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM my_table_1 a
JOIN my_table_2 b
ON b.id       = a.sale_id
WHERE a.value = '$user'
AND b.date_posted LIKE '05-05-2014'
```

This works correctly and shows me all of the sales for the specified $user for todays date.  I would like to change this so that it shows me all of the sales for todays date from all sales reps.  I can generate and array with all of the users IDs but am unsure how to insert this into the query

Anyone has an example?

Comment: What if you just remove WHERE a.value = '$user'?

Comment: Actually you'd remove `a.value = '$user' AND`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `in` operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM my_table_1 a JOIN my_table_2 b ON b.id = a.sale_id 
WHERE a.value in ('salesrep_82','salesrep_83')
AND b.date_posted = '05-05-2014'
```

UPDATED (you're right Rahul):

Using `LIKE` makes no sense without a wildcard like `%`

```
b.date_posted LIKE '05-05-2014'
```

use

```
b.date_posted = '05-05-2014'
```

instead.

Comment: @fightstarr20, condition `b.date_posted LIKE '05-05-2014'` is actually doing a exact match; in such case why not make it `b.date_posted = '05-05-2014'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the aggregate of all users combined, just use the `in` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM my_table_1 a
JOIN my_table_2 b
ON b.id       = a.sale_id
WHERE a.value in ('$user1', '$user2')
AND b.date_posted LIKE '05-05-2014'
```

If you want to have the list of sales by user, then you can combine the `in` with `group by`:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM my_table_1 a
JOIN my_table_2 b
ON b.id       = a.sale_id
WHERE a.value in ('$user1', '$user2')
AND b.date_posted LIKE '05-05-2014'
GROUP BY value
```

Note that depending on where you are running this query, it is generally not a good practice to just assign the string value to it because of problems such as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).